# How to tell if the PHP's garbage collector ran or not

Tags: garbage-collection, php-5.2

I have very bad code written in php. It consumes a lot memory, and then it brakes down, clears the sessions and bows!

I need to know when the  garbage collector runs, so that I can prove that this is indeed the case, but as far as i know php5.2 doesn't provide such of functions. The code is written by an inexperienced developer.

How can I tell if the PHP's garbage collector ran or not?

Comment: sorry pekka , that code is so long about 800 lines + 4 classes managed in very bad behavior , its awful and doesn't follow any coding standards

Comment: I think if you are coming to this type of question, it is time to seriously consider chucking the code in question and doing it correctly. How long do you want to maintain that mess? 800 lines isn't _that_ big to get sentimental over. Sometimes, garbage collection just means throwing it away :)

Comment: i had been consulted about it and  i had ruled about many bad ideas about this code i just need to prove that  PHP's garbage collector ran and cause it to break , and i will throw it away , its my pleasure tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to 5.3, PHP doesn't do garbage collection. The memory-management strategy is reference counting. Even in 5.3, garbage collection is an optional add-on to the main refcount mechanism.